# Retrieve Data from MySQL via AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I've been trying to figure this out for a week so I hope someone can help me. I've asked a few questions here, and with each one I think I get a little closer. This is running on a local machine with no internet connection.

I pull several images from my database on the page load with the initial of CW. I also pull other information that I may want to use at some point. I want to click on the image and go back to the database and show the name of the person. In the example below, I show three pictures, all of whom have the initial of CW. I'd like to click on the image and retrieve the name of each person. Currently it will only show the first person's name as that seems to be the one stored in memory from the initial load.

Specifically, I need help with the AJAX call or the PHP code as I'm not sure where the error is.

This is my test.php which includes the AJAX call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src = "../jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#photo").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getData.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response){
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response);
        }
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';

$result=$db->query("select * from monctonfir where initials = 'CW'");
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = '../image/'.$row["file"];
        $initial = $row["initials"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $location = $row["location"];
        $specialty = $row["specialty"];
?>
<body>

<h3>Employee Details</h3>

<div id="responsecontainer">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="photo">
        <a href=""><img id="photo" type="button" src="<?php echo $imageURL ?>"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>


</tr>
</table>

</div>
    <?php }

 } ?>

/<!--script type="text/javascript">
alert(<?= json_encode($name); ?>);
</script>-->


</body>

</html>
```

And this is my getData.php which does the SQL statement:

```
<?php

include_once 'db_connect.php';

$result=$db->query("select * from monctonfir where file = '$imageURL'");

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = 'image/'.$row["file"];
        $initial = $row["initials"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $location = $row["location"];
        $specialty = $row["specialty"];
}
 }
} 



?>
```

Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: `$imageURL` is not defined

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the Ajax call

Comment: $imageURL is not defined where - in the getData.php SQL statement? How do I return from the AJAX call? I thought the AJAZ was just to point to the PHP file and that is where all of the data is queried and returned

Comment: Any other help available?